# Adding to an existing value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie to mysql. I am making a table named inventory with 4 columns- id,name, price,quantity. Now if name already exists, I am to add the quantity to existing one else create a new row. (name is defined as UNIQUE). I am doing this on php.
$name, $quant,$price contain the values.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO inventory (Name, Quantity, Price) VALUES ($name,$quant,$price)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   Quantity    =  Quantity + $quant ,
  Price = VALUES(Price) ");
```

I am unable to understand why it's not working correctly. Sometimes Quantity updates correctly, most of the times it doesn't. Rest everything working perfectly. Just the problem with Quantity. Thanks for any help

EDIT: I defined the table on phpmyadmin. Here are the details:
    1   id  int(11)             AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY  
    2   Name    varchar(15) latin1_swedish_ci UNIQUE 
    3   Quantity    int(11)     
    4   Price   int(11)

EDIT:  **It was a cache problem . SOLVED**

Comment: Post the table definition please. (`SHOW CREATE TABLE inventory`)

Comment: Add mysqli_error() function in your query to show the error.

Comment: There is no error. It's just not adding correctly.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Edited the question. check EDIT

Comment: Also provide a sample which is not working.

Comment: Ok try this link http://siminternational.in/project/php_files/inventory.php?name='Lemons'&price=150&quant=10  The first entry works correctly. After this change values of quant. It should add up which it isn't.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Did you try it? Please tell me you know what I messed up

Comment: @MansimarSingh, you also should provide, what is already in the DB. You can use [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd9347/1) to construct your problem. For now it works like it should.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel So try this http://siminternational.in/project/php_files/inventory.php?name='ABCD'&price=150&quant=10 . After 10, put 5,6,10, 15 in quant. You will see what I am referring to. I am clearing the database manually right now.

Comment: Sorry, it works fine for me :-) At the end i get "Quant=46" ([10+5+6+10+15](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=10%2B5%2B6%2B10%2B15))

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Oh man! How could it be a browser problem? I was doing it on Safari and it gave problems. In Chrome, it's working perfectly. I just retried on Chrome (What the hell)

Comment: Might be a cache problem - happens to me again and again :-) - deactivate the cache while developing

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You must be a genius! Thanks. It worked. Weird Cache problem

Comment: Please write an edit to your question (in bold) that it has been a cache problem - so no one tries to find a problem somewhere else.

Comment: And learn about [**sql injections**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-injection/info).

Comment: And also check for negative numbers..i was able to set $quant as -1000 and your code happily accepted that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the $quant variable being updated correctly from your GET variable? Also please try the following query which should do the same as you are trying to do:

```
  mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO inventory (Name, Quantity, Price) VALUES ($name,$quant,$price)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   Quantity    =  Quantity + VALUES(Quantity),
  Price = VALUES(Price) ");
```

Answer (score 0):

problem with delaing with NULL values i guess
Try as follow

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO inventory (Name, Quantity, Price) VALUES ($name,$quant,$price)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
Quantity    =  IF((Quantity IS NULL), $quant,Quantity + $quant) ,
Price = VALUES(Price) ");
```

Comment: `Quantity = NULL` won't work. Use `Quantity IS NULL` instead.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Done Boss :)

Comment: Problem is not with NULL values. It picks up the first entry correctly. It's just adding consecutive entries randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that if $name, $quant, and $price are coming from users then this method is subject to SQL injection attacks and should not be used. Directly taking any user input without sanitizing it first is critical mistake that can lead security vulnerabilities.

We now have tools like PDO statements which prepare your SQL for entry into a databases. Please consider using a similar tool which prepares your statements when getting anything from a user.

Users are not to be trusted. Notice the binding of values below:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare('
    SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE username = ?
    AND email = ?
    AND last_login > ?');

$query->bind_param('sss', 'test', $mail, time() - 3600);
$query->execute();
```

The above code is from this article and it discusses the differences between using straight PDO and the mysqli version:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059